# Combining Regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I've some issues with a program which is fetching information out of an html table in Java.
To fetch information out of every column I use the following RegEx:

```
<td>([^<]*)</td>
```

This works very nice for me.
For fetching the Linknames I use this:

```
<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

This is also working very very good.
But sometimes I need informations from a column where a link is in. Therefore I wanted to combine these Regex with:

```
<td>([^<]*)</td>|<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>
```

I thought that it would work like this:

- It get every thing which is between `<td>` and `</td>`
- If the thing is a link it get also just the linkname

But this is not working. I'm not the best at RegEx so I need help to combine these two steps.

Thanks very very very much.

Comment: "I've some issues with a program which is fetching information out of an html table in Java." Don't parse html with a regex

Comment: What does _this is not working_ mean? Please give us the code you are using, and a short reproducible example that shows your problem clearly.

Comment: I know that a lot of guys don't prefer to parse HTML with regex. But it was always working for me. And I know that there must be a possibility to combine it.

Answer (score 1):

The code I'm using:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<td>([^<]*)</td>|<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>");

String line = "Here are the lines saved from the HTML downloader";

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
for (int startPoint = 0; matcher.find(startPoint); startPoint = matcher.end())
   {
        System.out.prinln(matcher.group(1));
   }
```

This is just a snippet - but thats how it works in general. (Normally the String is saved in an array).

Comment: `matcher.group(1)` returns `null` if a link was found.

Comment: They are already combined. To conjoin into a single capture group, Java would have to do _Branch Reset_, which is doesn't do. On every match, one of the 2 groups will be `null`, one won't.  All you have to do is check which one. And don't confuse `null` with the empty string.

Comment: I tried now to work with JSoup to parse all these things and it works a lot better - but thank you guys for your help!